# How to set up a parallel port printer in 12.04?

Tags: printing

After the upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 the parallel printer stopped working. It seems that that the parallel port is not detected. I didn't change anything in the bios and before it worked without problems.

I followed the instructions of this page:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems#Parallel_port_printer

```
$ lsmod | grep lp 
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 ppdev,lp,parport_pc
$ lsmod | grep ppdev 
ppdev                  17113  0 
parport                46562  3 ppdev,lp,parport_pc
$ lsmod | grep parport_pc
parport_pc             32866  0 
parport                46562  3 ppdev,lp,parport_pc
$ dmesg | grep par
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    0.000000] vt handoff: transparent VT on vt#7
[    0.515991] hpet0: 8 comparators, 64-bit 14.318180 MHz counter
[   18.007169] type=1400 audit(1371154439.505:2): apparmor="STATUS"    operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=654 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.007426] type=1400 audit(1371154439.505:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=654 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.007575] type=1400 audit(1371154439.505:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=654 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.007789] type=1400 audit(1371154439.505:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=716 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.008101] type=1400 audit(1371154439.505:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=716 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.008280] type=1400 audit(1371154439.505:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=716 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.019011] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   19.744248] type=1400 audit(1371154441.241:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" pid=964 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.744326] type=1400 audit(1371154441.241:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=965 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.744676] type=1400 audit(1371154441.241:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=965 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   19.744874] type=1400 audit(1371154441.241:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=965 comm="apparmor_parser"
$ ls -l /dev/lp* /dev/parport* 
ls: Zugriff auf /dev/lp* nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
ls: Zugriff auf /dev/parport* nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
$ ls -l /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport*/autoprobe* 
ls: Zugriff auf /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport*/autoprobe* nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
$ sudo cat /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport*/autoprobe*
cat: /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport*/autoprobe*: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
$ lpinfo -v
network lpd
network ipps
network http
network https
network socket
network ipp14
network ipp
network beh
direct scsi
direct hp
network smb
direct hpfax
$ /usr/lib/cups/backend/parallel
$ sudo /usr/lib/cups/backend/parallel
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This appears to be a kernel problem, see also http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2060188. You also might try the 3.5 kernel instead of the stock 3.2.

Comment: I upgraded to the 3.5 kernel, but the problem stays the same.